# Проблемы корректного insert в Oleddbcommand C#

Tags: c#, oledb, linq2xml

Проблема со внесением данных через insert into select - есть следующий кусок кода

```
  foreach (XElement anElement in xdoc.Element("ЗАКАЗЫ").Elements("Заказ"))
    {
        XElement dateElemet = anElement.Element("ДатаЗаказа");
        XElement id_uniElement = anElement.Element("НомерЗаказа");
        XElement nameElement = anElement.Element("ФИО");
        XElement ageElement = anElement.Element("Возраст");
        XElement maleElement = anElement.Element("Пол");
        XElement pregElement = anElement.Element("СрокОт");
        XElement codeElement = anElement.Element("Код");
        XElement localElement = anElement.Element("Примечание");
        XElement bioElement = anElement.Element("Биоматериал");
        XElement id_tubeElement = anElement.Element("НомерИсследования");


        string date = dateElemet.Value;
        string id_uni = id_uniElement.Value;
        string pat_name = nameElement.Value;
        string age = ageElement.Value;
        string code_uni = codeElement.Value;
        string id_tube = id_tubeElement.Value;
        id_tube = id_tube = id_tube.Remove(0, 2);//обрезаем 25 в номере пробирки
        string validate = "g";
        string biomat = bioElement.Value;

        if (localElement == null)
        {
            if (maleElement == null)
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id_uni", id_uni);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id_tube", id_tube);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("biomat", biomat);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pat_name", pat_name);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("age", age);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("validate", validate);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("code_uni", code_uni);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date);
                command.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                command.CommandText = "insert into result (id_uni,date_in,code_uni,id_tube,pat_name,age,validate_result,biomat,san_numb) select @id_uni,@date_in,@code_uni,@id_tube,@pat_name,@age,@validate_result,@biomat,san_numb from san_vac where id_uni='1990'";

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
            }
```

однако при исполнение кода в таблице result данные встают не в те поля. В каком направление смотреть ?Может есть какой-то "подводный камень"?

Answer (score 1):

В общем, как выяснилось в ходе сравнение результатов insert  в таблице - структура которая передаётся в таблицу бралась не из insert  а из последовательности добавление параметров. Почему так не знаю, буду искать информацию.